# TransportError 400 Elasticsearch with huge list of terms

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Search with small list of terms gives what i want

```
In [29]: small_list
Out[29]: [8096, 8105, 8114, 8116, 8128, 8130]

In [30]: sqs.filter(id__in=small_list)
Out[30]: [<SearchResult: web.listing (pk=u'8128')>, <SearchResult: web.listing (pk=u'8130')>, <SearchResult: web.listing (pk=u'8116')>, <SearchResult: web.listing (pk=u'8105')>, <SearchResult: web.listing (pk=u'8114')>, <SearchResult: web.listing (pk=u'8096')>]
```

but with thousands of terms gives below error:

```
In [32]: len(big_list)
Out[32]: 6305
In [33]: sqs.filter(id__in=big_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ravi/bit/wonder/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 516, in search
    _source=True)
  File "/home/ravi/bit/wonder/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ravi/bit/wonder/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 530, in search
    doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
  File "/home/ravi/bit/wonder/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ravi/bit/wonder/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 93, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/home/ravi/bit/wonder/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception')
```

Django==1.8

django-haystack==2.4.1

elasticsearch==2.1.0

Comment: A `400` error means that there is something wrong with your query. Catch and inspect the detailed error message that is inside the exception (`.info` on the exception object) to see what it is.

Answer (score 2):

By default elasticsearch is a limit on the query terms limited to 1024.

below query works for you

```
sqs.filter(id__in=big_list[:1024])
```

more info https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/LqywKHKWbeI